# Objective C : How to Insert text in Movie Player View?

Tags: objective-c

I am making a Apache Cordova Application.
On this Application, I used the plugin : Cordova Streaming Media plugin

Link is : https://github.com/nchutchind/Streaming-Media-Cordova-Plugin

I want to insert a "Hello World!" label on my movie but I don't know how to do that.

I think the script is : StreamingMedia.m
Link is : https://github.com/nchutchind/Streaming-Media-Cordova-Plugin/blob/master/src/ios/StreamingMedia.m

And function is : startPlayer()

Can you tell me where is my error :

```
-(void)startPlayer:(NSString*)uri {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:uri];

    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

// Listen for playback finishing
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];
// Listen for click on the "Done" button
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];
// Listen for orientation change
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
if (imageView != nil) {
    [moviePlayer.backgroundView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [moviePlayer.backgroundView addSubview:imageView];
}

    moviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

    [self.viewController.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

// Note: animating does a fade to black, which may not match background color
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];



     // Here my code :

     UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 0, 0)];
     label.text = @"Hello World!";

     CGRect frame = label.frame;

     frame.origin.x = 100; 
     frame.origin.y = 50;

     label.frame = frame;

     [self.viewController.view addSubview:label]; 
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. You can add a view to the app window/root controller view.
2. Create custom controller and add to his view `MPMoviePlayerController` like
   subView.

Comment: Than you for your reply.
I try to used : window.rootViewController.view
But there are no result

Answer (score 0):

Errors:

1. Your UILabel has 0x0 sizes. Just set up sizes :)
2. You send _rangeSlider to back of view via sendSubviewToBack. Remove it and it's start working.

And it seems you can just add subview to the MPMoviePlayerController view.

Comment: Thanks but I have the same result with this code :

 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 30)];

Comment: I'm test it with label sized to 100x100 and it's showing on player.

Comment: Can you show me your source code ? 
If there is no player, I can show my "Hello World!"